# How to resize and save gif file with Magick++ without animation loss

Tags: c++, image-processing, imagemagick, gif

I have next code for resizing images:

```
Image image;
image.read( imagePath.toStdString() );
Geometry newSize = Geometry(m_newSize.width(), m_newSize.height());
newSize.aspect(true);
image.resize(newSize);
image.write(newImagePath.toStdString());
```

This code work fine for non-gif files. For gif files I loss animation:
[image: Before resizing gif file]

[image: After resizng]

How to resize gif files without animation loss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution! Thank you MofX for right direction!

```
   Geometry newSize = Geometry(m_newSize.width(), m_newSize.height());
   newSize.aspect(true); 
   list<Image> frames;
   readImages(&frames, imagePath.toStdString());
   for (auto& image : frames)
        image.resize(newSize);
   writeImages(frames.begin(), frames.end(), newImagePath.toStdString());
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use readImages and animateImages to read all frames of the animation into an image list and to add them to an animation.

Look at this example at http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/STL.html:

```
#include <list> 
#include <Magick++.h> 
using namespace std; 
using namespace Magick;

int main(int /*argc*/,char **/*argv*/) 
{ 
    list<Image> imageList; 
    readImages( &imageList, "test_image_anim.gif" );

    Image appended; 
    appendImages( &appended, imageList.begin(), imageList.end() ); 
    appended.write( "appended_image.miff" ); 
    return 0; 
}
```

The only problem is, that the documentation says, that animatImages works only under X11

Comment: I tryied this. This not work. I got image with all frames in horizontaly sequence, but I need gif animation.

Comment: You shouldn't have just copied the sample code... I expected you to do a little work yourself after I pointed the way. You have to use animateImages instead of appendImages to make it work and than save it to a gif instead of a miff

Comment: I just not understand how to use animateImages for example. This function have list iterators as parameters and returning void. How I can get result of animation and write this? The same problem for coalesceImages method.

Comment: As far as I see it in the source code, the animation is generated in the first image. so imageList[0].write("animation.gif") should create the animation file. http://imagemagick.org/api/Magick++/STL_8h_source.html#l01957